# How can i regain access to change permissions on my files on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, permissions, mount, restricted-access

```
 chmod -rwx balfyp
chmod: changing permissions of 'balfyp': Operation not permitted
```

i changed the mount options on my wsl to fmask=111 suddenly i have zero access to my entire files on my /mnt/c please help me i just want to change my file access to only me to have rwx access to it please.

Answer (score -1):

I used `sudo chmod u+x [file]` that is how I solved the problem and I gained access to my file again thank you!.